# "Unable to open swap file for 'Makefile', recovery impossible" for every edited file in vim

Tags: swap-file

Upon editing any file I am now seeing this:

[image]

In order to isolate this I have deleted all of the contents of `~/.vim` or `~/.vimrc`.  I then consulted note here and recreated the `~/.vimrc with these contents:

```
if empty(glob('~/.vim/tmp'))
    silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/tmp
endif
set directory=$HOME/.vim/tmp
```

That also does not resolve  this issue for me.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: It's hard to say why this fails. It may be a hard drive or filesystem issue. First, please try if you see this error message without that snippet from your vimrc, e.g. try using `vim --clean`. If it does, check what is wrong with `$HOME/.vim/tmp` Perhaps you already have too many swapfiles there? So try with an empty one

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt  I had tried after removing everything to do with vim already including that directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following portion of a `~/.vimrc` is working for me .

```
" tell vim where to put swap files
if empty(glob('~/.vim/tmp'))
    silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/tmp
endif
set dir=/Users/steve/.vim/tmp
set backupdir=/Users/steve/.vim/tmp
```